# How to address a Scratch Org issue: max allocated capacity for Platform Cache Partition is 3?

Tags: salesforcedx

We are moving one of the projects to SFDX. When I push this `cachePartition` into a scratch org:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlatformCachePartition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <isDefaultPartition>false</isDefaultPartition>
    <masterLabel>myCache</masterLabel>
    <platformCachePartitionTypes>
        <allocatedCapacity>5</allocatedCapacity>
        <allocatedPurchasedCapacity>0</allocatedPurchasedCapacity>
        <allocatedTrialCapacity>0</allocatedTrialCapacity>
        <cacheType>Organization</cacheType>
    </platformCachePartitionTypes>
    <platformCachePartitionTypes>
        <allocatedCapacity>0</allocatedCapacity>
        <allocatedPurchasedCapacity>0</allocatedPurchasedCapacity>
        <allocatedTrialCapacity>0</allocatedTrialCapacity>
        <cacheType>Session</cacheType>
    </platformCachePartitionTypes>
</PlatformCachePartition>
```

I get an error:

> Total allocated capacity [5] exceeds the org limit [3].

Fine, with this line change `<allocatedCapacity>3</allocatedCapacity>` I can successfully push my code.

But the thing is I really need `5`. [Use Platform Cache with Scratch Orgs](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_apex_platformcache_for_scratchorg.htm) says

> Your scratch org has 3 MB of platform cache

But what should I do? This is a part of metadata which we track via VCS. The only option I see is a script to replace `5` to `3` on every push. It's annoying.

Does anybody know a better way to deal with such cases?

Comment: Surely there is no need for any cache at all on a scratch org since these are only providing a performance boost and your code should be written to work even if no cache exists... in which case, just exclude the cache definitions from push and pull via the .forceignore file...

Comment: @PhilW, great idea, thanks. The only drawback of this approach is that `force:source:convert` will not work and I need to remember to remove cache definitions from `.forceignore` when converting source to metadata.

Comment: hey @Eduard what's the filename and the parent folder of your cachePartition file? Is this a meta file or do I need a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best practice to write the Apex code to work whether or not platform caches exist. As such you should be able to simply use the .forceignore definition to exclude the platform cache definitions from push and pull operations and allow the scratch orgs to simply operate without the platform caches.

Comment: Just turned my comment into an answer. Feel free to comment further.

Comment: As per my last comment, we are using SFDX and we keep our source in this format  in our VCS. Now the issue is that if I add the cache definition into the `.forceignore` file, the `force:source:convert` command will not convert the cache definition in the metadata format. Hence, deployment will be without this setting. This makes the whole idea of storing cache definition in VSC pointless, unless you always remember to adjust `.forceignore` before running `force:source:convert`

Comment: In what circumstance do you need to do the force:source:convert at all? We hold the structure in the one (source) format and when we need to deploy to a non-DX org we just use force:mdapi:deploy.

Comment: Doesn't `force:mdapi:deploy` require the files to be in the metadata format? and you need to use `force:source:convert` to convert source into metadata.

Comment: No, it accepts deploying it from source format.